# Counting hyperlinks on Google Sheets formula

Tags: hyperlink, google-sheets, formulas

How do you count hyperlinked numbers within a simple Google Sheet formula?  Currently the =SUM(F6:CS6) (for example) does not count cells with hyperlinks.

Comment: What you you mean by "hyperlnked numbers within a simple Google Sheet formula?

Comment: This is for annual leave tracker for staff.  The spreadsheet I have has a hyperlinked holiday form to the number of days taken at that time.  For example '5' is in the cell and has a holiday form hyperlinked to it.  The formula adding all leave across the year, however, does not recognise the 5 as it is hyperlinked.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), because built-in functions cannot detect what formulas are entered in other cells, they can only access values. The discussion at [Google Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/dgIwG6GKtbA) confirms this. There is already a custom function posted there, but I wrote another one, a bit shorter and not case-sensitive:

```
function countLinks(rangeNotation, range) {
  var formulas = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeNotation).getFormulas();
  return formulas.reduce(function(acc, row) {
    return acc + row.reduce(function(acc, formula) {
      return acc + (/^=HYPERLINK/i.test(formula) ? 1 : 0);
    }, 0);
  }, 0);
}
```

Usage example: `=countlinks("A2:E10", A2:E10)`. Range notation has to be passed in as a string, because the function needs the range, not the values. But this also means it needs the second parameter  to be recalculated in case something changes in the referenced range.

Warning: this only counts the hyperlinks created with `hyperlink` formula. It will not detect the links created by pasting rich text into a cell. Those links (which really should never be created) are not detectable with Google Apps Script at present.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use scripts and just want a formula, this might serve you: [Countifs in Google Sheets with various 'different than' criteria in same row adds +1 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046939/countifs-in-google-sheets-with-various-different-than-criteria-in-same-row-add/58330177#58330177)

Particularly, the answer about the function COUNTA might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the format of the column you want to sum to numbers.