# Google Sheets: count numbers of HYPERLINKS where value > 0

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-apps, google-sheets-formula

I have a range of cells in Google Sheets
Some of these cells contain values (numbers) some with and others without HYPERLINKS
I need to count the number of hyperlinks for this range of cells if the value > 0

This function works fine, but does not include any cell-values
[Counting hyperlinks on Google Sheets formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231263/counting-hyperlinks-on-google-sheets-formula?rq=1)

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you want? Of course, please remove your personal information. And if you will use Google Apps Script, please add the tag.

Comment: This is a test sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QD_Fyxs6JqTDSPgTfoh3I8rpFkR_PNEqpRKrQjOh_Hk/edit#gid=0

The cell BL should show the total number of cells with a link and bigger than 0 - that's the code I need...

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for my poor English skill. Is this Spreadsheet the current situation which is the input value? Where can I see your goal which is the output you want? If the Spreadsheet doesn't include your goal, can you add it to your shared Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to think of about your solution. By the way, if you will use Google Apps Script, please add the tag.

Comment: The cell BL should show the total number of cells with a link and bigger than 0

Comment: it's the blue  cell

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about what you want to do. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Well, in this example the range of A3:AN3 contains cells with numbers. some of those numbers have a HYPERLINK. the blue cell (AO) should show the result of counting all cells with a hyperlink and the number higher than 0

Comment: Thank you for replying. About ``the blue cell (AO) should show the result of counting all cells with a hyperlink and the number higher than 0``, in your current shared Spreadsheet, the cell "AO" has 4. About this, what value do you need? And can you explain about the flow to your goal? I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Well there are 4 hyperlinks in the range - 2 with value 0 and 2 with a value higher than 0. So, the result should be 2. the other cells have also a number but no hyperlink

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand about your goal. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to calculate the number of cells which have the formulas of `=HYPERLINK()` and the value more than `0`.

  - This is run for one row and also there are the cells which have no hyperlink.
  - You want to achieve this using the custom function.
- As a sample, in your shared Spreadsheet, you want the number of `2`.

I could understand about your goal like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Your current script:

From the shared Spreadsheet, I confirmed your current script is as follows.

```
function countLinks(rangeNotation, range) {
  var formulas = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeNotation).getFormulas();
  return formulas.reduce(function(acc, row) {
    return acc + row.reduce(function(acc, formula) {
      return acc + (/^=HYPERLINK/i.test(formula) ? 1 : 0);
    }, 0);
  }, 0);
}
```

#### Modification points:

- In your current script, the values are not retrieved.

  - In this modification, both the formulas and values are retrieved from the cells.
- In your case, the formulas are retrieved from one row. So one `reduce()` can be removed.
- `range` is not used.

When above points are reflected to your current script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function countLinks(rangeNotation) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formulas = sheet.getRange(rangeNotation).getFormulas()[0];
  var values = sheet.getRange(rangeNotation).getValues()[0];
  return formulas.reduce(function(acc, formula, i) {
    return acc += (/^=HYPERLINK/i.test(formula) && values[i] > 0 ? 1 : 0);
  }, 0);
}
```

#### Usage:

When you use this as the custom function, for example, please put the following custom function to the cell "AO3" in your shared Spreadsheet.

```
=countlinks("A3:AN3")
```

#### Result:

When above script is used for your shared Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

## Updated: June 8, 2020:

At May, 2020, it seems that the specification for using the hyperlinks in Google Spreadsheet was changed. By this, unfortunately, above script cannot be used now. But, in the current stage, the hyperlinks can be retrieved using Class RichTextValue. So, in the current stage, it is required to modify above script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function countLinks(rangeNotation) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var richTextValues = sheet.getRange(rangeNotation).getRichTextValues();
  return richTextValues.reduce((c, row) => {
    row.forEach(col => {
      col.getRuns().forEach(r => {
        if (r.getLinkUrl()) c++;
      });
    });
    return c;
  }, 0);
}
```

#### References:

- [How to count new Google sheet links](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62245411/7108653)
- [How to extract the link from a cell now that links are not reflected as HYPERLINK?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61787891/7108653)

Comment: acc += (/^=HYPERLINK/i.test(formula) && values[i] > 0 ? 1 : 0);
  }, 1);  the result will be 3, right?

Comment: @Cătălin George Feștilă Yes. When your script is replaced, it retrieves ``3``.